# How to avoid empty <div> tags from th:if in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<div th:if="${user.admin}">
   Welcome, Admin
</div>
```

Above code leaves an empty  tag in the document if the user is admin. These empty divs creating alignment problems, how to avoid this?

Comment: What empty tag are you referring to here? Can you show us the HTML which you end up seeing if the expression is false?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show the formatted expected & actual outputs.

Comment: pls see my comment in below answer. The solution is to avoid any unwanted <DIV> tags.

Comment: The code in your question (containing only one `<div>`) does not generate the code in your comment (containing two `<div>`s).

Comment: old comments too deleted..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `th:block` instead of `<div>` for conditional display.

```
<th:block th:if="${user.admin}">
   Welcome, Admin
</th:block>
```

courtesy : https://anshulgnit.blogspot.com/2019/10/th-block-tag-in-thymeleaf.html

Comment: There is no need to use `th:block` here. Just use `<div th:if="${user.admin}">Welcome, Admin</div>`

Comment: my bad again. tried to pick a simple code to represent my requirement. I have just updated the sample above. The requirement is to avoid all divs, let me know if you can achieve it without th:block